ORA-50028: Invalid parameter binding when calling PL/SQL function from .NET Core Web API
this is my first question and I'm a bit excited! :)
In PL/SQL, I have a package named phonelib with a function called AddPhone.
PL/SQL Code:
create or replace package body phonelib is

  function AddPhone(v_phone_add_request phone_add_request)
    return phone_added_response is

    v_phone_added_response phone_added_response := phone_added_response();
  begin
    insert into phone
      (phoneid, phonenumber)
    values
      (phone_seq.nextval, v_phone_add_request.phonenumber);

    v_phone_added_response.phoneid := phone_seq.currval;
    v_phone_added_response.phonenumber := v_phone_add_request.phonenumber;
    commit;
    return v_phone_added_response;
  exception
    when others then
      rollback;
  end AddPhone;

end phonelib;

Object Types:
create or replace noneditionable type phone_add_request as object
(
  phonenumber varchar2(20)
)

create or replace noneditionable type phone_added_response as object
(
  phoneid number,
  phonenumber varchar2(20)
)

I can successfully call this method using PL/SQL, but I want to connect to PL/SQL from a .NET Core Web API.
C# CODE
public PhoneAddedResponse AddPhone(PhoneAddRequest addPhoneRequest)
{
  PhoneAddedResponse addedPhoneResponse = new PhoneAddedResponse();

  using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
  {
    connection.Open();

    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand())
    {
      command.Connection = connection;
      command.CommandText = "begin :v_phone_added_response := PHONELIB.AddPhone(:v_phone_add_request); end;";
      command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      command.BindByName = true;

      // Input parameter
      OracleParameter inputParam = new OracleParameter("v_phone_add_request", OracleDbType.Object);
      inputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
      inputParam.Value = addPhoneRequest;
      command.Parameters.Add(inputParam);

      OracleParameter returnValue = new OracleParameter("v_phone_added_response", OracleDbType.Object);
      returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
      returnValue.Value = addedPhoneResponse;
      command.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

      // Execute the function (no need for reader)
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }

  return addedPhoneResponse;
}

Error Message
Error: response status is 500

Response body
Internal server error: ORA-50028: Invalid parameter binding

How to fix this issue? Are there any alternative methods you can recommend?
Thank you...
I'm writing a backend using PL/SQL. I want to connect it to a .NET Core RESTful web API to expose this backend and develop a frontend. However, I cannot send data to my PL/SQL function from the web API. There is a type mismatch. How can I fix this?

You SQL code can be simpler fiddle
